# About Loading image in Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a spinner to show that the content is loading, when someone clicks on an icon. Basically when someone clicks the hyper-link, the page takes time to load and meanwhile I want to show a spinner/'loading image'. How to implement that?

Thanks in advance

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/fav-icon.png" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <meta name="keywords" content=" my webpage" />
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="wrap">
        <!--- start-top-grids---->
        <div class="top-grids">
          <div class="top-grid">
            <div class="product-pic">
              <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/search_page.png" title="watch" /></a>
            </div>
            <a href="directory.php">Directory</a>
          </div>
          <div class="top-grid">
            <div class="product-pic">
              <a href="http://example.com"><img src="img/news.png" title="shoe" /></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"> News</a>
          </div>

          <div class="top-grid">
            <div class="product-pic">
              <img src="img/payment.png" title="view pay" />
            </div>
            <a href="#">View Pay</a>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"> </div>
          <div class="clear"> </div>
          <div class="clear"> </div>
          <div class="clear"> </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:
1) Place "spinning wheel" image in one div.
2) Add "Loading..." text

When your page is loading set that div to display and once your page is loaded successfully set div to display: none.

```
    <div id="progressIndicator" style="display: none;">
       <div style="background-color: Transparent;" >
           <img src="Images/indicator_mozilla_blu.gif" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small; cursor: wait"
             align="absMiddle" alt="" />&nbsp;Loading...
       </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

When you are clicking on Image button do not directly call server side function. Instead call a client side function like "CallServerSideFunction()" and from that function call your server side function. You can try something like below:

In Javascript function:

```
 function DisplayProgress() {
        document.getElementById('progressIndicator').style.display = '';
    }

function HideProgress() {
        document.getElementById('progressIndicator').style.display = none;
    }

function CallServerSideFunction() {
        DisplayProgress();
        document.getElementById("btnCallServerSideFunction").click();
        HideProgress();
   }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Dear sir i want when i click on a image button then loading image show..in my code there are 3 image button and they are hyper links.and i want that when i click any of them then their should be a loading    icon till next page fully load.